# What is {name:slug} in route parameter in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

```
Route::get('/click/{name:slug}', [NameController::class, 'click']);
```

What is {name:slug}? Is it constraint for parameter? How to use it? Is it build-in function?

I think slug is the simple url name. I want to understand it. Thanks.

Comment: According to https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing - `name` will be the handler function parameter to bind to, while `slug` is the entity property (or database-column) to use to automagically identify which `Click` object you want to be loaded by Laravel into the handler function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read more about [laravel model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-model-binding), specifically [customizing binding key](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-the-key).

Here's a description for your code:

The `name` part refers to a model so in your code there should be a `Name` model, the `:slug` part refers to the attribute of that model. Meaning when calling the endpoint/route `/click/this-is-a-name-slug` it will query the model `Name` using that attribute

```php
// NameController

public function click(Request $request, Name $name)
{
  // Laravel will inject the Name model in $name automatically based on the slug
  // If no Name matched the slug then the controller will return 404
}
```